# Selectively render equations with MathJax

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I am trying to have MathJax typeset equations on my entire document, except for specific divs. Right now, my HTML document has the following set up:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"> </script>
```

and a bunch of other configs specified in

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config" > //options </script>
```

Let's say the body contains:

```
<div id="one"> $A^x$ </div>
<div class="two"> $B_x$ </div>
```

When the page loads, both A^x and B_x are typeset. However, I would like to tell MathJax not to render the equations in div.two on page load (only later). Is there a simple way to do this?

Note that I am not trying to do something like

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,document.getElementsById('one')[0]])();
```

but rather "render everything, minus the divs which class 'two' ".

Thanks.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you are using TeX-input, you can specify classes in the configuration of the tex2jax pre-processor, e.g.,

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  // ...
  tex2jax: {ignoreClass: "class2"}
</script>
```

[See the MathJax documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/tex2jax.html) for more details.

Comment: Is it still possible in the latest version? I cannot find the `ignoreClass` option in the [present documentation](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html)

Comment: Yes it is possible. The option is called `ignoreHtmlClass` now, see http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/document.html?highlight=ignoreHtmlClass